# Set wallpaper without wallpaper manager, call default set as methods

Tags: android, android-intent, wallpaper, android-wallpaper, wallpapermanager

[image: wan to call default methods]

i am trying to call default wallpaper set as method but its not working
i have tried so many code over stack but its not working so please any one have solution for it please reply

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpg");
            intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set As"), 200);
```

Comment: In which android version?

Comment: i am trying on android oreo

Answer (score 0):

```
Can u try the below code:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
```

Comment: Ok on which device you are testing

Comment: honor 7 with android oreo 8.0.0 and also tried with Moto G5s Plus with android Oreo